# R Normalize eigenvectors in spectral clustering then plot

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, eigenvector, normalize

I am following this http://www.pnas.org/content/suppl/2008/12/22/0802806106.DCSupplemental/0802806106SI.pdf to achieve `spectral clustering` on my `correlation matrix`. I have calculated `eigenvalues/vectors` and have chosen the k-most (`k=5`) significant pairs. The resulting matrix looks like this:

```
    V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
-0.033  -0.099  -0.046  -0.014  -0.013
-0.010   0.012   0.069   0.087   0.002
 0.010  -0.002   0.114  -0.053  -0.012
0.0023   0.001  -0.013  -0.006  -0.005
 0.004   0.054  -0.011   0.090  -0.049
```

Now I need to `"normalize each row to unit length"`. How do I go about that? From what I understand, I calculate the length of each row by taking the squareroot of the sum of each value in the row squared as `|a|` then divide each value in the row by `|a|`?

If that's the case, how then would I plot these 5 values in the `Euclidean Space?` `5D plot?` Most resources on the web I've found to do with normalizing to unit length deal with `x,y,z` and can be plotted on a `3-D plot`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your assumption is correct, you want

```
df_rn <- df / rowSums(sqrt(df^2))
rowSums(df_rn^2)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

so all rows are now normalized by their l2 (euclidean) lengths.

Not much can be said about plotting in 5d: it is impossible. Usually 2d (rarely - 3d) projections are drawn. The question of projection plane is open; it depends on what are you trying to show.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone with a different approach for plotting, but the normalization requirement remains the same.